# create array from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm receiving this JSON below

```
{
    "category": "test",
    "sealing_temp_1": "",
    "sealing_temp_2": "",
    "sealing_temp_3": "",
    "level_sensor_1": "",
    "level_sensor_2": "",
    "level_sensor_3": "",
    "check_pack_1": "",
    "check_pack_2": "",
    "check_pack_3": "",
    "comment": ""
}
```

and I would like to turn it to this structure and save

```
{
    "category": "test",
    "sealing_temp": "['a', 'b', 'c']",
    "level_sensor": "['x', 'y', 'z']",
    "check_pack": "[1, 2, 3]",
    "comment": ""
}
```

Can someone guide me, I tried to use a `for..in` but got lost in the process

Comment: add your tried code

Comment: @NinaScholz — There's nothing in either code block that isn't entirely valid JSON.

Comment: I'd recommend using `Object.keys` maybe?

Comment: @NinaScholz JSONLint tells me it's a valid json, I'm not sure how you differentiate an object to a json

Comment: @Jonathan I think the difference is that JSON is a text format, and an object is what is parsed in a JS engine. I personally find your examples to be valid JSON, but it seems to be a matter of semantics.

Comment: @evolutionxbox any idea how to achieve the result I need?

Comment: @Jonathan I think you might need to use a mix of regex and `Object.keys` to achieve it.

Comment: `for..in` should work fine, but we can't help you about being "lost" if you don't show us the route you tool. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the key and if it has digits at the end in it, then use it for an array to fill.

This proposal change the object and deletes unwanted properties which values are now in an array  collected.

```js
var object = { category: "test", sealing_temp_1: "s1", sealing_temp_2: "s2", sealing_temp_3: "s3", level_sensor_1: "l1", level_sensor_2: "l2", level_sensor_3: "l3", check_pack_1: "c1", check_pack_2: "c2", check_pack_3: "c3", comment: "cc" };
    
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    var parts = k.split(/_(?=\d+$)/);
    if (parts.length === 2) {
        object[parts[0]] = object[parts[0]] || [];
        object[parts[0]][parts[1] - 1] = object[k]; // subtract one for zero based array
        delete object[k];
    }
});
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, the code does what expected. can you please tell me what the delete object[k] does?

Comment: it deletes the property with the given reference, for example `object['sealing_temp_1']`. the value is previously moved into an array, the two line above of the `delete` statement.

Comment: it works well on a fiddle but I get this error on a workflow configuration 'Object does not support this property or method', any alternative for Object?

Comment: what it the detailed error? which method does not work?

Comment: error message: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" | I think it's Object.keys(object)

Comment: on which browser do you get this error? `Object.keys` is ES5.

Comment: it's a 32bits software, not sure what it uses, I tried for (var k in object) and it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147919/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-jonathan).